# i want to getting first character index at line, in wpf richtextbox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

When I entered the linenumber I would like to know the index of the first character of the line.

Each time click the button 
print text on richtextbox1.

and I would like to know the index of the first character of the output line.

### this is my code :

```
private int GetTextPositionAndLength(int position, int lineIndex, out int length)
{
    int richtTextLineIndex = GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex);
    int index = 0;
    length = 0;
    return index + richtTextLineIndex;
}

private int GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(int lineIndex)
{
    // What should I enter the code?
    int index = 0;
    return index;
}
```

help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private int GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(int lineIndex)
    {
        int index = 0;

        var rtb = yourRichTextBox;

        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
            rtb.Document.ContentStart,
            rtb.Document.ContentEnd
        );

        var alltext = textRange.Text;

        string[] lines = alltext.Replace("\n", "").Split('\r');

        if (lineIndex > lines.Count())
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineIndex");

        for (int i = 0; i < lineIndex; i++)
        {
            index += lines[i].Length;
        }

        return index;
    }
```

Hope, it helps